# Which has more internal energy, a bucket of hot water or a bucket of cold water

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

Online answer I found :
The bucket of hot water has more internal energy.
Internal energy depends on the amount (mass) of substance and the kinetic energy of the molecules of the substance.

My thinking to it :
Since it is written dependant on mass, then swimming pool has more mass than bucket of hot water.Since it has even higher K.E , then how can Bucket of hot water have more Internal energy than swimming pool?

Comment: One thing is total amount of energy in J, other thing is specific energy in J/kg or molar energy in J/mol. The latter two depend on temperature, the former one on temperature and amount of substance. So hot water in the bucket has higher specific energy in J/kg, the pool higher energy in J.

Comment: Ok thnx.I understood

Comment: If you thought and searched about it little longer, you would not propably post your question at all.